# Constructing Tortuous Tours

Tags: combinatorics, construction

We'll define a *tour* of some **N** x **M** grid as any sequence of tiles such that the first tile is the bottom left corner, any two consecutive tiles are adjacent, and every tile appears in the sequence exactly once. We'll call a tour *tortuous* if there is no set of four consecutive tiles in the tour that forms a 1 x 4 (or 4 x 1) rectangle.

For which **N**, **M** does there exist a *tortuous tour*?

Example (two tortuous tours of 4 x 5):

[image: Example Tour 1][image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can construct a Hilbert-curve-like path for any rectangular mxn...

Comment: @JoeZ. Hilbert curve solves $2^n \times 2^n$.

Comment: And $2^n \times 2^{n+1}$, if you glue two of them together.

Comment: @JoeZ True, so you can get $2^n \times k\cdot2^n$ like that.

Comment: I don't know if you can get $k > 2$ in all cases. If you chain them side-by-side when $n$ is even, it creates segments of length 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40638/discussion-between-ben-frankel-and-joe-z).

Comment: It's certainly possible whenever at least one of $m$ or $n$ is even; if the height is even, one can just use the patterns of right-up-left-up or right-right-up-left-left-up to fill up 2 or 3 columns at a time, with some special business on top (e.g. right-down-right-up-right) to connect the stacks. I don't know about odd $m$ and $n$ though.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I'm not sure that's always true. Here's a [counter-example](http://i.imgur.com/NppMeYl.png).

Comment: @BenFrankel Oh, I see. I guess I hadn't considered what would happen at the third column.

Comment: What program are you using to make these grids?

Comment: @Deusovi, Actually it's a program I wrote myself :). The source is on github [here](https://github.com/BenFrankel/Grid-Coloring).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is possible for

> All $M$ and $N$ with $M, N > 1$.

Here are the gadgets I need to prove it.  Note that it doesn't matter which corner of the rectangle you start since you can always rotate the picture.

[image]

By using gadgets (1) and (2), you can essentially subtract 3 from the height of the grid.  (1) works for grids of even width, and (2) works for grids of odd width (just add more up and downs for wider grids).  Note that (1) only works on grids of width at least 8, and (2) works for grids of width at least 5.

After subtracting 3 from the height enough times, you'll be left with a grid of height 2, 3, or 4.  If the grid is height 2, just zig-zag back and forth and fill in the rest of the grid.  If it is of height 3, just repeat gadgets (1) or (2).  If it is of height 4, then use gadget (3) for grids of odd width and gadget (4) for grids of even width.

This essentially takes care of all cases except $6 \times 6$.  But this is possible too, as shown by gadget (5).

Comment: Great solution! Mine is not as simple. Very minor comment: technically, as defined, 1 x [1,2,3] are also possible.